# Conditional formatting to mark rows depending on contents

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, conditional-formatting

I have an excel sheet that for the forseeable future will remain as a Work In Progress regarding a project. To easily be able to keep track of rows that need some work I would like to create a macro that changes the background color depending on certain rules, according to this pseudo-code:

```
For each row n {
  if any cell on row n contains a question mark, background of cell [A,n] should be red
  if cell [B,i] is empty, background of cell [A,n] should be red
}
```

What's the easiest way to implement above pseudo-code to rows 4 to, say... 1000?

**Note regarding the question mark:**

It may be a standalone question mark, or it will be text followed by a question mark. I want it to match any question mark on that row.

**Note regarding rule precedence:**

If both rules were to trigger on the same row, I want the cell to end up red.

Comment: @Ramhound Nor did I claim that you were. I am unable to find anywhere in excel 2013 where I can begin playing around with VBS or the like. What I have found is that the wizard style selection under Conditional Formatting leaves a lot to be desired, and the other choices don't seem to do anything near what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Conditional Formatting, apply the formula `=OR(B1="",MATCH("?",1:1,-1)>0)` to column A.

The `MATCH` portion will look for a question mark anywhere in any field in the row, not just a standalone question mark.

Answer (score 1):

Using this formula `=OR(B1="",A1:C1="?")` gave me results that would seem to be what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: Sorry to have missed the part where you said that the "?" could be preceded by text. This formula accounts for that: `=OR(B1="",OR(RIGHT(A1:C1,1)="?"))`